# use external function in Yii Controller (Helper function)

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, yii

I develop some web sites by CodeIgniter,it has got helper file,which can be written by developer to use some function in class.

Now I'm developing web site by Yii,and I have php file which has function that should be used in Controller. How can I import them and use them in Controller method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we are doing it is this:

We have a file in lib called **SharedFunctions.php**, and lib.* are imported in config/main, so that Yii, autoloads the SharedFunctions file..

> In SharedFunctions.php file

```
Class SharedFunctions{
    public static function lib() {
        return new SharedFunctions();
    }

    public function myfunction($params) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now anywhere in Yii app we can use any function defined in the SharedFunctions file as

```
SharedFunctions::lib()->myfunction($params);
```

Comment: where is the lib folder located?

Comment: i cannt see any folder named lib here, is this a user created folder and user created class(SharedFunctions), like extensions??